# Using HtmlAgilityPack with c# to Find Nested repeated class name section

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm having trouble figuring out what the query (XPath?) is to get to a nested element as follows.  I'm wanting to get the "200" out of the span.  the things I know for sure are the out class is "top2 bigone" is a div and that I want the span inside that with the class "top2 bigone".  I put my C# below that of course does not work.

thanks

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class='top1 bigone'>
        <span class='counts numbers'>100</span>
    </div>

    <div class='top2 bigone'>
        <span class='counts numbers'>200</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My broken code:

```
var input4 =
            (from inputx in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("top2 bigone")
             where inputx.Attributes.Count > 0 && inputx.Attributes["class"].Value == "counts numbers"
             select inputx).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, tested and working:

```
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class = 'top2 bigone']//span[@class = 'counts numbers']");

if (node != null)
{
    string number = node.InnerText; // 200
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("node = null");
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a try when I get back to my real computer